# Can anyone help elaborate on the message below regarding API limits on Unlimited Edition? This is directly from help.salesforce.com

Tags: api, unlimited

"Unlimited. However, at any high limit, it is likely that other limiting factors such as system load may prevent you from using your entire allocation of calls in a 24–hour period."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular phrase is simply saying that, at some point, you're likely to run into other limits that will prevent you from utilizing 100% of what you're allowed (there *is* a limit, but it's nigh-impossible to reach it). For example, you might run into row-locking problems, search indexing problems, longer query times, lost cursors from overlapping queries, etc. In other words, you can use as much of the system as you'd like to try, but at some point some other system limit will become a problem. The hardware they are using is not *unlimited*, so realistically, you cannot have *unlimited* calls. However, you will have an absurd number of calls to the point where "weird things" can happen as opposed to being rate-limited at the lower editions.